# Asp.Net Core I'm getting 404 error problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm getting a 404 error but the problem is solved when I refresh the page.

This url is being called by a service. In this case it always gets error. 
If I refresh the page the problem is getting better. The page opens.

Where is the problem? Can you help me?

My Callback Parameter:

```
CallbackUrl = $"{httpContext.Request.Scheme}://{httpContext.Request.Host}{httpContext.Request.PathBase}/company/payment/callbackpayments/?data=" + model.Transaction.Id.ToString()
```

IActionResult:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult CallbackPayments(string data)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index","Dashboard",new { area="Company"});
}
```

Comment: My guess: you're missing a `/` between `{httpContext.Request.Host}` and `{httpContext.Request.PathBase}` in the `CallbackUrl`.

Comment: And the framework provides a nice UriBuilder  class and nobody uses it, (even in this code the String.Format sugar is used partially....)

Comment: Try to share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

`[HttpGet]`

to this:

`[HttpGet("company/payment/callbackpayments/?data={data}")]`

or make sure your controller has `/company/payment` in a route attribute
`[Route("company/payment")]`

Comment: I get a 404 error on my page. But it works correctly when I refresh the page